# Identifying the first iteration of a loop, c#

Tags: c#, xml, loops, xmlnode

This is very basic but i was wondering if there was a better way of programming the following concept.

```
 for (int j = 0; j < node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (j != 0) row.Cells[1].Value += ", ";
                    row.Cells[1].Value += node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes[j].Name;
                 }
```

Basically im outputting nodes in c# to a table and i want each attribute name to be separated with a comma. The issue is that obviously for the first instance of the loop i wish not to have the comma preceded it, ie i could not just have

```
row.Cells[1].Value +=  ", " + node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes[j].Name;
```

otherwise the output in the cell would look something like:

```
, name, day
```

instead of

```
name, day
```

So although this works, it seems a waste of the computer time to check each time it loops that this is indeed the first iteration of the loop, especially as this loop is nested in a recursive method. Is there a better way of doing this?

(Bearing in mind that node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes.Count in the for loop conditions may be 0, ie node(which is a xmlNode) could have no child nodes, so the the loop doubles up as an existence check for the children too. )

I hope i explained this well!

Comment: Have you considered `String.Join` ? It does this automatically.

Comment: Just start with the second iteration, and always add `,` before you add the next string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `string.Join`

```
var commaSeperated = string.Join(", ", node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes.Select(a => a.Name));
```

Comment: Thanks! I dont quite understand the .Select(a => a.Name), how does this do specifically, i know is functionality is to go through the names of each attribute of the element but i dont know how

Answer (score 2):

Use the `string.Join` method. Here's a flashy way to do the whole thing in a single line:

```
row.Cells[1].Value = string.Join(", ", node.ChildNodes
    .SelectMany(node => node.Attributes.Select(attribute => attribute.Name)))
```

Comment: 1) Make sure you have `using System.Linq;` as one of your namespace imports at the top of your file. 2) If the `ChildNodes` isn't a generic enumerable type you may have to call `Cast<Node>()` on it before calling `SelectMany`. You may be better off writing this out as a foreach-loop if the Linq stuff confuses you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with a loop, start with the second iteration:

```
string result = array[0];
for(int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
    result += ", " + array[i];
```

that's the general idea